# avro maven plugin can not generate code for map schema

Tags: java, maven, avro, avro-tools

My avsc file is

```
{"type" : "map",
 "name" : "valueMap",
 "namespace" : "example.avro",
 "values": "long"
}
```

but after I used `mvn compile`, no error reported but no specific class generated.
when the avsc schema is about `enum` or `record`, the avro maven plugin works well.
How can I generate the related class for map schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no class to generate here since it's not a record or enum type (as you found, do work), it's just a collection.

You can serialize a `Map<String, Long>` directly into Avro, so don't think you really need this schema file unless you were to reference/import it into another record